# Add background of bitmap

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap

There is a class that creates a bitmap picture and cuts it into tiles. I need to add a background to this. I tried different ways. But it didn't work out :(

```
internal constructor(bitmap: Bitmap?, parentWidth: Int) {
    var bitmap = bitmap
    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap!!, parentWidth, parentWidth, false)
    val tileWidthAndHeight =
        bitmap.width / NUM_TILES
    for (i in 0 until NUM_TILES) {
        for (j in 0 until NUM_TILES) {
            val yStart = i * tileWidthAndHeight
            val xStart = j * tileWidthAndHeight
            val b = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                bitmap,
                xStart,
                yStart,
                tileWidthAndHeight,
                tileWidthAndHeight
            )
            if (i == NUM_TILES - 1 && j == NUM_TILES - 1) {
                tiles!!.add(null)
            } else {
                tiles!!.add(
                    PuzzleTile(
                        b,
                        i * NUM_TILES + j
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```